# can any one give me the answer about this java loop

Tags: java, loops

I don't know what this loop does. Can anybody tell me?

```
for (String Number : Num) {
  lineIndex[count] = Integer.parseInt(Number);
  count++;
}
```

Comment: search in google for-each loop

Comment: I think this wouldn't compile at all.

Comment: @PrasadKharkar Assuming count is declared before, and lineIndex is an int array/list, and Num is a String collection, it should compile just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [for-each loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html).

`Num` is some object which implements `Iterable<String>` like a String[] array or a collection like for example `ArrayList<String>`.

The loop is executed once for each entry in that data structure. In each iteration of the loop, `String Number` is a different entry.

What the loop does exactly, is to read each entry from `Num`, parse it as an integer, and put it into the `lineIndex` array.

Answer (score 1):

This is a for-each loop, where `Num` is a collection of `String` and `Number` is the current element in the collection in each iteration.

In the loop body, it is just assigning the parsed string to an element in lineIndex array, and incrementing count.

It is equivalent to:

```
for (int i=0; i<Num.Length; i++)
{
    String Number = Num[i];
    lineIndex[count] = Integer.parseInt(Number);
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you Should read Core java 2. Volume I, Fundamentals or java effective.

Comment: Answers should stand on their own and not just point to an external resource. Especially not when the pointer is that vague (these books cover a lot more topics than just for-each loops).

Comment: By this question, I think he is still in the stage of learning Java, so I think he should read these books.

Comment: Although that might be the case, it is not an answer to the question. I think you should read meta.stackoverflow.com. What? You don't know which question on meta I actually mean? See, that's how useful such a statement is.